# Send all OpenVPN traffic through proxy or TOR proxy?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn, tor

I have an OpenVPN server and I want to be able to route all requests that are made to that OpenVPN server through a proxy, so that the requests will look like they are made be the internet address of the proxy. For example, a normal request looks like this:

`request -> openvpn -> send data back to user with the IP of the machine`

When I want it to go through TOR or a proxy:

`request -> openvpn -> tor or proxy -> send data back to user with the IP of the proxy`

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For this, I'm assuming that you have installed tor using `apt-get install tor` and not using the TOR browser bundle.

1. Add this line to the `/etc/tor/torrc` file to tunnel VPN traffic:

   ```
   SocksPort 9150 PreferSOCKSNoAuth
   ```
2. Then you will need to tell OpenVPN to use a proxy.
   Add this to your VPN config file:

   ```
    socks-proxy localhost 9150
    socks-proxy-retry
   ```
3. Restart tor:

   ```
   sudo service tor restart
   ```
4. Now you should be able to run OpenVPN AFTER tor has established a connection to the TOR network.

   ```
   sudo openvpn --config path/to/vpn/config/file
   ```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm portsharing 443 (on 4433) with nginx and when I add those two lines to the OVPN config everything fails. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Are you supposed to put the socks-proxy lines in the server side or client side config file?

Comment: This is configuring the client? The question asks for server.